# Should I upgrade the CPU for lightweight home server?

Tags: processor, desktop

I recently built a new gaming PC, which leaves me with my previous parts that currently are going unused.

What I wanted to do was setup a small home server that can host a light survival Minecraft server (latest version, around 5 people), local website hosting/building/deploying, and at the same time use it for file hosting / as a FTP server.

All of these have caused massive strain on the system, most likely due to the CPU bottlenecking the system so I'm looking for what part(s) I should upgrade. My budget is around $100-200.

#### Current Parts

- **GPU**: GTX 1070
- **CPU**: i5-8600k
- **PSU**: 450 Watts
- **RAM**: 16GB DDR4